# how to prevent captcha verification

Tags: java

I am reading Google search response in my Java code using Apache Http Client using `HttpGet` method, but after some time Google sends the captcha verification. After Google sends the Captcha verification, I get nothing rather than captcha.

How can I prevent my code from captcha verification?

Comment: title might be "prevent", not "resolve".

Comment: google tries to verfiy you when you are requesting too frequently.

Comment: If there's a captcha, it means that you shouldn't access this page programatically, so your question should be reconsidered...

Comment: you could uses google's official search-api, but if Im not mistaken its not free

Comment: yes, I am sending request too frequently

Comment: I have used Google Search API but, API have it's limit that is not useful for me

Comment: I have seen a software that do same as i am doing but that software pop up a window that contains the captcha that google send i can fill captcha and continue, but in java i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Are you really asking how to get around a limit that Google has purposely put in place because of exactly what you are doing? I'm sorry but I think this question is out of line.

Comment: Perception : I am asking how to bypass from captcha verification that is all want to know in java. when i am reading google search response Google giving me captcha response. Now i want to know how to fill that captcha so that i can continue to my work.

Comment: Tell me, why google put a captcha to stop you?

Comment: So in the end the qustion is: How do I send a post request with java? or How to download and show an image? or How to parse the response to figure out the image url? If it's all of them consider individual questions.